# Material Design drawer not showing in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to figure out why the drawer widget is not rendered in my Flutter Web page.

```
    import 'package:responsive_builder/responsive_builder.dart';
    
    class HomeLayout extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomeLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) => Scaffold(
        drawer: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop
            ? null
            : NavigationDrawer(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              NavigationBar(),
              Expanded(
                child: Navigator(
                  key: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
                  onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
                  initialRoute: HomeRoute,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

...

```
class NavigationDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: SizedBox.shrink(),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xff2acccc),
            ),
          ),
          DrawerItem('Login', LoginToAdmin),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
class NavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationBar({ Key key })  :  super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenTypeLayout(
      mobile: NavigationBarMobile(),
      tablet: NavigationBarTabletDesktop(),
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
class NavigationBarMobile extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationBarMobile({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: NavBarLogo(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying out Flutter Web, and run the project with "flutter run -d chrome"
When I click on the burger menu nothing happens, apart from the ripple effect.
I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong in my ResponsiveBuilder() widget, but what that is, is not clear to me.

this incredible pen demonstrates that it should work [codePen](https://codepen.io/FeelHippo/pen/wvJKBBz)

Any help will be much appreciate

Comment: I am assuming that this part: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop disables navigation bar.

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you for your answer. I did try to replace that part with (among other things) a plain  "Drawer()", but to no avail. That bit comes straight from the responsive_builder.dart docs. sizingInformation.isMobile also had the same effect

Comment: Could you try using drawer: NavigationDrawer() without condition? What happens then?

Comment: same effect, the burger icon is there and the ripple effect fires, but the drawer is not shown

Comment: can you show all properties of Scaffold ?

Comment: `Scaffold(
        drawer: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop
            ? null
            : NavigationDrawer(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              NavigationBar(),
              Expanded(...`

Comment: would be great if you just edit your post with opening as much code of HomeLayout as possible, otherwise it is not easy to understand what is going on. I just tried to use simple example with responsive_builder and it works just fine

Comment: sure, I just did that, thank you for your help buddy

Comment: I think that inside of NavigationBar you have burger menu button that opens drawer manually, right? What is the code of opening a drawer ?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add an `AppBar()` to your `Scaffold()` for the drawer to be visible, similar to the following:

```
return Scaffold(
  drawer: const MyDrawer(),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Hello'),
  ));
```